# About the set of all function from rational numbers to real numbers that is continuous

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

$A=\{f|f:\Bbb{Q} \to \Bbb{R}, f^2 =f , f \ is \ continuous \}$, now is A countable ?

I think A is countable because $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=c$ ,$c \in \Bbb{Q}$ is belong to A ,but I can't prove this is all exactly answer .

Comment: Your argument shows that $A$ is _at least_ countably infinite, but not that it is actually countable.

Comment: By the way, when you write $f^2=f$ do you mean that $(f(x))^2=f(x)$ for all $x$ or that $f(f(x))=f(x)$ for all $x$?

Comment: f(f(x)) is correct.

Comment: @amirbahadory: Are you sure?  The question is much more natural if it means $f(x)^2=f(x)$ (for one thing, $f(f(x))$ doesn't even make sense if $f(x)\not\in\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: But what would $f(f(x))$ even mean if $f(x)$ happens to be irrational?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each irrational number $\alpha$, consider the function $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=0$ if $x<\alpha$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x>\alpha$.  This is an element of $A$, and gives an injection from the set of irrational numbers into $A$.  Since there are uncountably many irrationals, this means $A$ is uncountable.

(This answer assumes $f^2=f$ means $f(x)^2=f(x)$ for each $x\in\mathbb{Q}$.  If instead $f^2=f$ means $f(f(x))=f(x)$, you can similarly show $A$ is uncountable by letting $f(x)=x$ for $x<\alpha$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x>\alpha$.)

Comment: Does this satisfy the continuity property though?

Comment: Actually for $f(f(x))=f(x)$ the first construction still works well as long as $\alpha$ is an irrational in $(0,1)$ -- of which there are still uncountably many.

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun: Yes! The function is continuous at every point in its domain! (It is not _unformly_ continuous, but that was not asked for).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh, I see that now!